# Printing matrix with numpy, python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I just want to return a matrix.  What am I missing?

```
import numpy

print matrix([[0,1],[1,1]])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fib.py", line 2, in <module>
     print matrix([[0,1],[1,1]])
NameError: name 'matrix' is not defined
```

Comment: use `numpy.matrix` instead of `matrix`. You need to access the class within the `numpy` module

Comment: When you see `NameError` it is a hint the that the name is not defined correctly. As Ben has mentioned this is due to the import not being enough to use `matrix` in this way. You have 2 options to do what you want: `import numpy` then `numpy.matrix` or `from numpy import matrix` then `matrix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call it like:

```
print numpy.matrix(...)
```

or do something like this (to avoid writing the whole word `numpy`):

```
import numpy as np

print np.matrix(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print numpy.matrix([[0, 1], [1, 1]])
```

`matrix` is defined in the `numpy` module. `import` won't dump the contents of the module into the current namespace; you need to refer to `numpy.whatever_thing_you_want_from_the_module`.